# Is there a way to focus element from querySelectorAll()?

Tags: javascript

I want to focus my dropdown elements from keyboard (up and down keys).

My code:

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("div.dropdown-content > a");
var i = 0;
var focused = matches[i];

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            i++;
            focused.focus();
            break;
        case 38:
            i--;
            focused.focus();
            break;
    }
};
```

But it's actually not working. Console does not report any errors.

Comment: what's an `i` ? also focus methos has no return value so why do you assign it to focused var? is it related to that?

Comment: yes I will edit, but It doesn't solve. i is counter which child is selected now.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow key up is `38`, down is `40`, also check `i` range between 0, nodes.length

```js
const matches = document.querySelectorAll('div.dropdown-content > a');
let i = 0;
let focused;
if (matches.length > 0) {
matches[i].focus();
focused = matches[i];
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 40:
            if (i < matches.length - 1) {
                i++;
            }
            matches[i].focus();
            focused = matches[i];
            break;
        case 38:
            if (i > 0 ) {
                i--;
            }
            matches[i].focus();
            focused = matches[i];
            break;
    }
};
}
```

```css
a { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-content">
 <a href="#">Link</a>
 <a href="#">Link</a>
 <a href="#">Link</a>
 <a href="#">Link</a>
 <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't have to check (matches.length > 0), because I use HTMX request, but i thought about adding checking i is in range in the same way. I use bulma dropdown with text input, I don't know maybe It's not working because text input is already in focus?

Comment: I also have redeclaration of const matches, let i and let focus. When I change them to var it not report errors

Comment: This code properly focus, for example other text-input's, but not my bulma dropdown, when I will have a solution I will get know

Comment: This code properly add or remove class 'is-active' to my dropdown elements, so they looks like they are focusing, but probably not focus them (I have css properties to focused element). When I hit enter It occurs its not focused also.

Comment: @user17259141 not all elements can be focused, like `<div>`, `<span>`, they require to add attribute `tabindex` to get focused

Comment: I gave tabindex=10 to a tag now it's focusing. I had to add enter key event to populate text-field.

Answer (score 0):

You keep focusing the same element, `focused` is not updated when `i` changes.

Also, the keycode for down arrow is `40`, not `37`.

Finally, you should check that `i` is always between `0` and `matches.length - 1`.

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("div.dropdown-content > a");
var i = 0;

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 40:
            if(i < matches.length - 1) i++;
            matches[i].focus();
            break;
        case 38:
            if(i > 0) i--;
            matches[i].focus();
            break;
    }
};
```

You can also focus the first item when you reached the last one and vice versa :

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 40:
            i = (i + 1) % matches.length;
            matches[i].focus();
            break;
        case 38:
            i = Math.abs(i - 1 + matches.length) % matches.length;
            matches[i].focus();
            break;
    }
};
```